# Can we create new_strings.xml with strings.xml in values folder for sting strings (Android)?

Tags: android, string

I have two xml files in `values` folder for strings:

1. new_strings.xml
2. strings.xml

From `strings.xml` I can access string as follows:

```
String str = getString(R.string.app_name);
```

How can I directly access from `new_strings.xml`?

Answer (score 11):

By the same way you're accessing the values in strings.xml file.

Example :

strings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name_1">First app name</string>

</resources>
```

new_strings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name_2">Second app_name</string>

</resources>
```

In your java code you can do :

`R.string.app_name_1`

`R.string.app_name_2`

and you can access both values which are in two different xml files.

As the doc said:
file location:

```
res/values/filename.xml
```

The filename is arbitrary. 
The `<string>` element's name will be used as the resource ID.

compiled resource datatype:
Resource **pointer to a String**.

Comment: Yes. But I want it to apply even on language change. Say these two files are present in two folders "values" and "values-es". In case of language change, when strings are retrieved from "values-es", it returns string from "values" folders "new_strings.xml" whereas it should return string from "values-es" folders "new_strings.xml"

Comment: I'm not sure about the interest of making two different xml files for each folder since the access to the values are doing by the same way.

Comment: @ZouZou, If the filename is arbitrary, does that mean that we actually only need one file `everything.xml` within the `values` folder? Then we can place the contents of dimens.xml, str.xml, and styles.xml into everything.xml?

Answer (score 1):

To give you a really short answer:

Yes, you can access to all strings in both files regardless of the filename. Although it's generally a good practice to keep all strings in one file, I do personally find it useful to separate strings into multiple files, especially for localization purposes, which brings me to the next point:

Yes you can access to the localized strings in other locale folders, e.g. `values-es`, as long as it contains a translated copy of all string files in the `values` folder.

For example, if you have `strings.xml` and `new_strings.xml` in your `values` folder, make sure you also have both of those files in your `values-es` folder in order for your app to display the localized strings in Spanish.

Hope this clarifies things up for you =)